# Error : Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, model

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for `{{node max_pooling2d_18/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 2, 2]](Placeholder)` with input shapes: `[?,32,30,1]`.

what code I have written? Can anyone explain why?

```py
model_shallow = models.Sequential()
model_shallow.add(layers.Conv2D(32,3, activation='relu',
                          input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model_shallow.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model_shallow.add(layers.Conv2D(64,3, activation='relu'))
model_shallow.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model_shallow.add(layers.Flatten())
model_shallow.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model_shallow.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model_shallow.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']) 

model_shallow.summary()
```

Comment: I am specifically getting error on line, model_shallow.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2))

Comment: "What code I have written" - shouldn't you know that better than we do?

Comment: The code you posted does not correspond to the error message.